# reduce time precision of time series to milliseconds

Tags: python, pandas

When parsing data files I have seconds like these:

```
1.296999421
```

which is currently being displayed in pandas like this:

```
<Timestamp: 2011-04-16 00:00:01.296999>
```

with a dtype of 'datetime64[ns]'
but I know that the original measurement only had millisecond precision.

Is it possible to generate a pandas timeseries that uses only milliseconds precision?
One of my goals is to precisely join different timeseries based on their millisecond counters.

So I would like to have only

```
<Timestamp: 2011-04-16 00:00:01.297>
```

so that I can match this time-stamp precisely in other time series.

In other words, is there a 'datetime[ms]' and how can I convert non-sequential timestamps to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HYRY solution is right, but pandas won't know how to deal with it

using latest pandas 0.11-dev, timedeltas now have full support

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-deltas

```
In [25]: a = np.random.rand(8)*10

In [26]: a.sort()

In [27]: a
Out[27]: 
array([ 0.72062151,  1.02039858,  2.07877837,  3.94256869,  5.5139672 ,
    6.80194715,  6.83050498,  8.63027672])

# trick is to pass a nanosecond value directly
# pandas keeps all values internally as timedelta64[ns]
In [5]: pd.Series((np.round(a*1000)/1000)*1e9,dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
Out[5]: 
0   00:00:00.721000
1   00:00:01.020000
2   00:00:02.079000
3   00:00:03.943000
4   00:00:05.514000
5   00:00:06.802000
6   00:00:06.831000
7   00:00:08.630000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

And if you need this as a Timestamp

```
In [8]: pd.Series((np.round(a*1000)/1000)*1e9,dtype='timedelta64[ns]') + pd.Timestamp('20110406')
Out[8]: 
0   2011-04-06 00:00:00.721000
1   2011-04-06 00:00:01.020000
2   2011-04-06 00:00:02.079000
3   2011-04-06 00:00:03.943000
4   2011-04-06 00:00:05.514000
5   2011-04-06 00:00:06.802000
6   2011-04-06 00:00:06.831000
7   2011-04-06 00:00:08.630000
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: So there I was thinking, that I better leave Jeff alone with all my timeseries issues.. you can't say I didn't try! ;)

Comment: I have now the problem that `pd.io.date_converters.parse_all_fields()` does not like timedeltas as input? Do you have an idea for that?

Comment: So, if internally it is kept as a 64-bit float anyway, can I actually be ever sure to be able to test equality between these timestamps? Would a better approach be to go for something using np.allclose() or at least a test that considers an epsilon error and not equality? I was hoping to achieve testable equality by going to milliseconds.

Comment: didn't see your byline! you can do td.astype('int') if u want, but they should compare == in any event as they are int64 under the hood (so they are exact numbers of ns)

Comment: don't know about the parsers, prob not updated to handle timedeltas....you could either store the start and end dates or an int64

Comment: astype('int') does not work because the parsers expect 00..59 as seconds.

Comment: turned out that it is enough to do np.round(seconds*1000)/1000 for all time series. As you reminded me, they are stored internally as int64, so I can match them exactly with each other on that big number! ;) Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you convert `1.296999421` to `<Timestamp: 2011-04-16 00:00:01.296999>`. I think you can create a datetime64[ms] array by following step:

```
a = np.random.rand(100)*10
a.sort()
t = np.array(np.round(a*1000), dtype="timedelta64[ms]") + np.datetime64("2012-03-01")
```

Then you can use `t` as the index of your DataFrame. Pandas will convert this to `timedelta64[ns]`.

Comment: obviously one cannot convert 1.29699xxxx to that full time stamp, it was just an example, because I am concerned with the seconds treatment.